# Remote and local authentication fails on Mongo DB 3.0.7 (installed on Amazon EC2)

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an admin user:

```
> db.createUser(
... {
... user: "administrator",
... pwd: "password",
... roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
... }
... )
Successfully added user: {
    "user" : "administrator",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

and now i'm trying to use it for enter with:

```
ubuntu@***ip number***:/etc$ sudo mongo --port 27017 -u administrator -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

This is what returns:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.7
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2015-10-27T15:33:25.670+0000 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
    at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271:32)
    at (auth):6:8
    at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271
```

Mongo is installed into an Amazon EC2 machine with Ubuntu.

What is missing?

Comment: Did you open the port in the security group?

Comment: tcp inbound and outbound for 27017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `userAdminAnyDatabase` role allows the user to grant access (for itself, or any other users) to any other database, however, that does not automatically grant that admin user read/write permission on all those databases (though it can bestow them upon themselves). You can resolve your authentication issue by granting the user the additional role `readAnyDatabase`.

```
db.createUser(
{
user: "test1",
pwd: "password",
roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }, {role:"readAnyDatabase",db:"admin"} ]
}
)
```

[Link to MongoDB docs: Create a User Administrator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/)

Answer (score 0):

Change on mongod.conf ( stop first mongod service. Ex: `sudo service mongod stop`):

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

for:

```
bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Now you can restart (Ex:`sudo service mongod start`)

Now you can enter in the same machine normally typing `mongo`, but for example, if you try to do it with robomongo gui before makes the test success the ip but don't success the user login. The user and login was created before with a pwd and roles for `userAdminAnyDatabase` and `readAnyDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

Now just type in your machine:

```
mongo --host (ip number here) --port 27017 -u username -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

And connect to remote Database.