# Cannot login as an admin user in Mongo 3.6

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm simply trying to create an admin user in mongo 3.6 and log in. I ran:

```
 $mongo
db.createUser(
 {
   user:"AdminMark",
   pwd:"fghtyyy",
   roles:[{role:"root",db:"admin"}]
 }
)
```

It says: `Successfully added user`

Then tried to log in:

```
mongo -u AdminMark -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

And I enter password. But I get:

```
 2018-03-05T20:40:07.689+0000 E QUERY    Error: 18 Authentication failed.
at DB._authOrThrow (src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271:32)
at (auth):6:8
at (auth):7:2 at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1271
exception: login failed
```

This happens but locally and on my server. What's going on?

Im following the tutorial here: https://tecadmin.net/create-drop-users-in-mongodb/#

The contents of my mongod.conf file is:

```
    # mongod.conf

    # for documentation of all options, see:
    #   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

    # Where and how to store data.
    storage:
      dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
      journal:
        enabled: true
    #  engine:
    #  mmapv1:
    #  wiredTiger:

    # where to write logging data.
    systemLog:
      destination: file
      logAppend: true
      path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
      bindIp: 127.0.0.1


    #processManagement:

    #security:

    #operationProfiling:

    #replication:

    #sharding:

    ## Enterprise-Only Options:

    #auditLog:

    #snmp:
```

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33372968/1246159). Didn't work.

I can I very simply add a mongo 3.6 admin user, then log in to Mongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error was caused by creating the user in the default database (`test`) and authenticating using the `admin` database.

If you don't specify the database name when connecting, the `mongo` shell will default to the `test` database.

What you're missing is switching to the `admin` database before creating the user.

This sequence of commands should work:

```
$ mongo

> use admin

> db.createUser({
    user:'root',
    pwd:'hunter2',
    roles:[{role:'root',db:'admin'}]
})

$ mongo -u root -p --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Also as answered by @Kevin earlier, you need to enable auth to tell MongoDB to enforce authentication. **If you don't enable auth, MongoDB will authenticate you but not enforce authorization.** This can be achieved using the config file by adding the `security` section, or starting `mongod` using the `--auth` parameter.

Please see the [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) for more details on MongoDB's security features and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your mongod.conf file and make sure **authorization** is set up as **enabled** (in the security section)
If you are connect the MongoDB from outside of your server, please also remove bind ip (in net section) from mongod.conf file.
I hope it can help.

#### Here is my setting up

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

#processManagement:
security:
 authorization: enabled
```

Comment: hi, i copied the contents of mongod.conf to the question. I dont see how i can set authorization....

Comment: I just add my config file. I hope it can help.

Comment: Did you restart service? Please try to run "sudo service mongod restart"

Comment: I also add quote mark when I try to login: mongo -u "your name" -p "your password" --authenticationDatabase "admin"

Comment: I believe you are so close. :)  I hope other people can offer you more thought.